# Does Java 7 run on only x64 bit MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, deployment, javafx, java-7, executable-jar

I want to deliver self-contained application packages on Windows, Linux and Mac so I have build my JavaFX application on all three platforms. I will allow my users to download these native bundles from my application's download web page but I have a confusion regarding MAC users because For Linux and Windows, JDK/JRE 7 comes in two download options

1. for x86
2. for x64.

but for MAC we have only option for x64.

Java Download [Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) shows Java/Jre is not available for 32 bit MAC OSX to run JavaFX application. Does it mean JavaFX will run on only x64 bit MAC OSX?

If it is so, then my issue has been solved, as I have already bundled my Javafx application as a "Self-Contained Application Packages" after run custom build.xml script on x64 MAC OSX but if it is not so, the user can also run JavaFX application on x86 MAC OSX but in that case my "Self-Contained Application Packages" for mac would not run on x86 MAC OSX.

So I am planning to give an additional zip file that either contains app (without copy of jre) or a plain self executable jar. But I'm bit worried regrading - what exactly I need to bundle into that zip file with self executable JAR so requirements must be met to be able to run my JavaFX application in following conditions?

conditions are : -

1. If user has x86 MAC OSX.
2. If java is already installed on user's system. And he would not like to download the "Self-Contained Application Packages" from our download page.
3. Big download size.

So what among the following two options suits if user have x86 MAC OSX or if he has already installed java on his system or he would not like to download "Self-Contained Application Packages" from download page due to big download size?

Option are -

1. APP ( without inbuilt copy of JRE)
2. Or only a self executable jar.

I am not sure that Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) or later version can run on x86 system.So in case of #1 option the user may have trouble if he is using x86 system. Then he may need to change info plist file and replace the JavaAplicationStub.

In case of #2 option I think is better as the user need to download the JRE only and the JAR should run using "java -jar" command.

Please suggest which option is better in case if JavaFX application can run on x86 bit MAC OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Java 7 run on only x64 bit MAC OS X?

Oracle Java 7 for OS X is only available for 64 bit architectures, there is no 32 bit version of the software.